# VS 2008 - SQL CE 3.5 database, Dataset Error - MSDataSetGenerator not generate designer.cs code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dataset, sql-server-ce, msdatasetgenerator

I have problem with generating designer.cs code from datatable in VS 2008. I open SQL CE 3.5 database in server explorer and drag database table into designer and I get this error message:

> Custom tool error: Failed to generate code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I right click on the dataset1.xsd a click on "Run custom tool", then I get this message:

> The custom tool 'MSDataSetGenerator' failed. Object reference not set to an instance object

Have anyone this problem? Do you have tips for solve this problem? Some days ago, it worked correctly.

Comment: Same problem on PC (W7 64) with VS2010 and VS2012 installed. VS2008 reistallation did not solve the problem. New VS2008 installation in VirtualBox works.
If I copy whole project from VBox installation it stops generate designer.cs code too. So it isn't project or dataset xsd file problem.

Answer (score 2):

Uncle Google just told me to start VS2008 with /resetskippkgs command line switch. It solved my problem. VS2008 started to generate code for dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Open xsd file as xml and check connection on the top of file. If connection is wrong it generates nad throws similar error. Just remove all connections from connection node on the top of xsd file.